# Why package log instance can't share to another package in Golang

Tags: go

My project has some packages, I don't want to pass log instance from one function to another, instead use a global log instance in there packages.

Here is the demo  I have done, but run `go run main.go`, nothing print in logs/replica.log.

What's wrong with my code?

```
├── log
│   └── replica.log
├── logs
│   └── logs.go
├── main.go



$ cat main.go
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "./logs"
)

func main() {
    logs.Debug("hello")
}

$ cat logs/logs.go
```

```golang
package logs

import (
    logging "github.com/op/go-logging"
    "os"
)

var log = logging.MustGetLogger("replica")
var format = logging.MustStringFormatter(
    `%{time:2006-01-02 15:04:05} [%{level:.4s}] %{shortfile}: %{message}`,
)

func init() {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("log/replica.log", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    backend1 := logging.NewLogBackend(f, "", 0)
    backend1Formatter := logging.NewBackendFormatter(backend1, format)
    logging.SetBackend(backend1Formatter)
}

func Debug(args ...interface{}) {
    log.Debug(args)
}
```

Comment: defer f.Close() - the file is closed when init() completes.

Comment: @foo right, my mistake, I will correct and check

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the *defer* in logs/logs.go:init() is the issue. Why is that the issue? Let's take a look at the [Go Language Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec), specifically the section on [Defer statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements):

> A "defer" statement invokes a function whose execution is deferred to the moment the surrounding function [...] reache[s] the end of its function body [...].

The file is closed when the end of the *init* function body is reached. Keep in mind, there's no good way to gracefully close a global file.

Comment: All exits from `main()` should be done via a dedicated function (call it `die()` if you want) which should run "destructors" of global objects and then call `os.Exit()` with appropriate code.